# Sharpen reflected image

Tags: optics, lenses

I'm currently working on a project which is a kind of hologram.

As an object I have a display and with a plexiglass I use the reflection so that I can see the display inside the plexiglass.

The experimental setup looks something like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/8js7N.jpg

But the problem is that the picture in the plexiglass is blurred: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZKA1T.jpg (The blur is also visible in reality, so it has nothing to do with the photo)

My idea is to sharpen the image with a plano-convex lens. However, I cannot find a plano-convex lens large enough to cover the whole display. Besides, I would need very high diopters to keep the focal length as short as possible.

Do you have an idea how I can sharpen the image in the plexiglas best?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's very likely that the problem is that you're getting reflections off of both faces of the plexiglas plate, so you're getting two images on top of each other, slightly offset.

You can fix this by putting a linear polarizer (e.g., from Edmund) in front of your image source, and tilting the plexiglas at about 57 degrees ([Brewster's angle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brewster%27s_angle)) to the image source.  Light of one polarization will reflect off the front surface only.  Effectively,there won't be any light of the other polarization.

Answer (score 1):

I think the blurred picture comes from the pour quality of the plexiglass, use a real glass, and it will not blur,  no lens can make a blurred picture sharp . the lens could make your picture smaller or larger, and it has not to be very large.

Comment: Better quality material would help, but isn't this just multiple reflection from each surface of the plexiglass?